# What does "iTunes err = -3259" mean?

Tags: data-transfer, itunes, itunes-u

I am downloading some iTunes U content in iTunes and am getting

```
stopped (err = -3259)
```

on a number of the downloads.  I was hoping to find a list of err codes, but no luck.  Found a lot of forum posts for other error numbers, but not that one.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I turned off "Allow simultaneous downloads" and now it is consistently downloading without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I search some I find that it happen because of antivirus:

> What seemed to work for me was
>   disabling anti-virus software during
>   the load process. I killed my
>   antivirus and then hit refresh on all
>   of the podcasts that failed with err =
>   -3259 and they all finished successfully.
>
> Long term I think we need to get apple
>   to resolve this issue, but in the
>   meantime you can temporarily disable
>   your anti-virus, complete your
>   downloads and then bring the
>   anti-virus back up.

And some where said that it because parental control:

> Some of our users are reporting that
>   unchecking Podcasts from the Parental
>   Controls preference pane has resolved
>   the issue. For some of our customers,
>   simply going into: Edit - Preferences
>   - Parental Control and unchecking Podcasts

Comment: It wasn't parental controls or anti-virus.  I disabled the "Allow simultaneous downloads" and now it works fine.